# Is it possible to change in line attributes using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to change an in line html dir attribute in the English version of a mixed Arabic and English Twitter feed from dir="ltr"to dir="rtl" in order to avoid full stops appearing in the wrong place in the included Arabic tweets. (The English tweets would be then displayed right to left but would at least be grammatically correct, whereas the Arabic tweets when displayed left to right have a full stop in the middle of the sentence.)

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

I've read that you can change an inline style using CSS as in the example below:

Div with in line style for red background:

```
<div style="background: red;">
</div>
```

CSS to change red to yellow:

```
div[style] {
background: yellow !important;
}
```

Can this be done for other attributes such as dir?

The div I need to change is in an iframe. Changing dir="ltr" to "rtl" in Firebug displays all text right to left which is what I want.

```
<iframe id=“twitter-widget-0” class=“twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered” scrolling=“no”   height=“862” frameborder=“0” allowtransparency=“true” style=“border: medium none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px; width: 300px;” title=“Twitter Timeline”>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div id=“twitter-widget-0” class=“root timeline ltr customisable-border twitter-timeline not-touch twitter-timeline-rendered var-static var-narrow” lang=“ar” data-scribe=“page:timeline” data-iframe-title=“Twitter Timeline” data-dt-long=“%{day} %{month} %{year}” data-dt-short=“%{day} %{month}” data-dt-abbr=“%{number}%{symbol}” data-dt-months=“Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec” data-dt-hours=“hours” data-dt-hour=“hour” data-dt-minutes=“minutes” data-dt-minute=“minute” data-dt-seconds=“seconds” data-dt-second=“second” data-dt-h=“h” data-dt-m=“m” data-dt-s=“s” data-dt-now=“now” data-profile-id=“2645852642” data-timeline-type=“profile” dir=“ltr” data-twitter-event-id=“0”>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

The site I'm developing is here:

http://dominodev1.co.uk

(You will see that in the English version the Arabic tweets have a full stop at the right hand edge of the bottom line which is in fact the middle of the sentence.)

Many thanks,

Phil

Comment: No, you can't change attributes with CSS.

Comment: Side note about your `!important` : It's a proof you have a design problem. You shouldn't need that. I have very big projects (sometimes with one hundred .less|.scss files) and absolutely no `!important`.

Comment: You're using Wordpress with the Avada theme, yet you've added almost all scripts and styles inline in the head, you're inserting iFrames left and right, and it seems to me like the entire design is, maybe not wrong, but certainly not very good ?

Comment: You should really set the directionality in HTML (this is what W3C recommends) and consider the entire design. The directionality should be set according to the writing system, and texts in different writing systems should normally be separated from each other (in elements with their own directionality).

Comment: Thanks very much. I agree about the !important. I also try to avoid this. The example above was just something I found that was demonstrating the use of the div[style] selector and not something I had included in the design. I haven't customised the Avada theme and so scripts and styles are all as the authors of the theme provided so I'm afraid I'm not responsible for any errors there. It would also be beyond my abilities to comment on them. It does seem that the directionality is set using dir attributes by the multi-lingual WPML plugin that I am using to switch between Arabic and English.

Comment: I'm trying to change the css direction property but am having difficulty finding the right selector. If my client Tweeted from two accounts, one for each language, I would have no problem as I could use Widget logic display separate widgets for each language. The problem is that he mixes the two languages - tweeting in both from one account.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way isn't to change the atribute (you can't from CSS) but to change the [direction css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) :

```
someSelector {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: But would that change the way bootstrap renders it ?

Comment: @adeneo I hope so but I never tried bootstrap (and don't intend to).

Comment: I've tried it, but have never tried this, so I have no idea, guess the OP will have to try it and see ?

Comment: @adeneo that's not the big issue if the bootstrap doesn't allow to render then can use !important.

Comment: @C-linkNepal - that depends, bootstrap obviously pulls in those attributes and uses them for something, probably to set styles when creating elements, and there's no guarantee that setting another style elsewhere, even an important one, will override whatever Bootstrap does, that depends entirely on what exactly Bootstrap does internally.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is what I am trying to do, but while `.twitter-timeline .e-entry-content {direction: rtl;}` works in Firebug I can't make it work from my style.css It maybe, if this is possible, that the switching from one language to another somehow resets the css, though, I'm afraid this is beyond my ability in css to verify or comment.